# Can't view "Public View" of "Scheduled and Sent Messages" as a Super User admin in CiviCRM. Incorrect URL being constructed

Tags: civimail, joomla, permissions

(Joomla 3.9.8)
(Civi 5.14.1)

When signed in as a Super User in CiviCRM, I am getting an error when trying to view the "Public View" of "Scheduled and Sent Messages" for Civi Mailings.

The error message I get is:
`You do not have permission to access this page.`
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kjnSC.png]

One thing I noticed is that my url loses 'administrator' when clicking "View Public View" and instead looks like this:
`index.php?option=com_civicrm&task=civicrm/mailing/view&id=413&reset=1`

If I manually remove index and replace it with administrator the url works:
`administrator/?option=com_civicrm&task=civicrm/mailing/view&id=413&reset=1`

I checked the Global Configuration in Joomla for `CiviMail: view public CiviMail content` and it is indeed allowed for a Super User, but it still does not work. The only way to get the 1st, Civi generated url to work is to set `CiviMail: view public CiviMail content` to enabled for all the public. I don't want that.

So my idea was to go into Civi's core, find out where this url is being created and change the `index?` part of the url to `administrator`. I am not sure where to find this. Does anyone know where this url is being constructed? If there is a better way of doing this, I would like to know as well.

Answer (score 2):

This may or may not be related, but there is an ongoing issue relating to when `/administrator` is included in the path.  See https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/joomla/issues/5 for details.

Comment: It certainly looks promising. I was looking for where these URLs were being defined. I'd rather hard code the URL just for that one instance though. Changing a dynamic link like the ones explained in that thread you found could change dozens of URL constructions. On another note, it is also a CMS specific issue for those wondering. I tried it on Wordpress and the issue does not occur.  I'll check it out after the weekend. Thanks for the tip.